# Bulk PDF Rename - Removing Suffix

Tags: powershell, pdf, batch-rename

I have 1000 PDFs in a folder `C:\Users\1003911\Desktop\pdf`.

File names are something like `38852ad-Layout1`, `38852s-Layout-1`, and so on.

I need to remove "-Layout1" from all the PDFs.

I tried few options from this site, but I cannot get it right. Anyone can give me exact code what I should write?

My code is:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\1003911\Desktop\pdf' |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Substring(0, $_.Name.Length-12) }
```

I used this to rename and it worked, but the .pdf extension is removed. How do I retain it?

Comment: Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\1003911\Desktop\pdf' | rename-item -newname { $_.name.substring(0,$_.name.length-12) }                                                                                i used this to rename. It worked. but .pdf extension is removed. How do i retain it?

Answer (score 0):

You got the right idea.  I personally think it's easier to use $_.basename and put it in a sub-expression and tack on the .pdf at the end.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\1003911\Desktop\pdf  | rename-item -newname {"$($_.basename.Replace('-layout1','')).pdf"}
```

also note, I used [string] replace method instead to remove the "-layout1"

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Other version of Ricc solution:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\1003911\Desktop\pdf" -file -filter "*.pdf"  | rename-item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace('-layout1','')}
```

This version :

- Take only file, not directory
- Filter on pdf only
- Rename Name and not BaseName + concatenation